# Why does dropping my laptop's AC adapter in the floor make it work again?

Tags: ac, adapter

For several months now I've had trouble getting my AC adapter I use to charge my laptop to work. It's one of those typical looking things, with two ends and a big bulky rectangular thing in the middle.

No matter how much I've tried to fiddle with both ends to make the adapter work, like replugging it to the laptop back and forth, it never works. On the other hand, I've had a 100% success rate of getting the adapter work with the following method:

I plug it in to the laptop and to the electrical outlet, grab the rectangular bulky adapter thing and drop it straight down on the floor from about a 15 cm (5,9~ inch) height. As soon as the adapter slams against the floor, it works again until the next time I unplug it from the electrical outlet.

What's the science behind this, why does this work?

Comment: oooh! Percussive Maintenance!

Answer (score 9):

There must be a solder joint of a component which is broken. A mechanical shock moves the component and it makes contact again. That could be a fire hazard, not to mention more components coming loose in their solder joints due to all the mechanical shocks. Please buy a new adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your power supply contains a mechanical component that no longer switches due to aging.

This could be a mechanical relay or a bimetal connection where I'd rather guess a mechanical  relay.

Comment: Possible, but unlikely in modern switchmode power supplies.